# Nginx rewrite params issue

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

How can I remove the multiple slash from the URL http://myserver.com//data/app?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2 via rewrite rule in nginx?

I am trying with rewrite regex but failing to do so successfully with complete query string i.e with foo1 and foo2 params in redirect.

Comment: Where is the `//` coming from? The `rewrite` directive operates on a normalized URI, and will not see the embedded `//` or the `?` or the query string.

Comment: one of our client is sending such request. We can't make the fix in client side due to some weird reasons. So we are trying to fix it on nginx side to that request should start working.

JFYI, we have set merge_slashes off and we are manually normalising the url by rewrite url as the nginx is not normalising the url somehow (with default merge_slashes on)

Comment: The value `$uri` should be normalized but the value `$request_uri` is not. I have seen problems when people use `$request_uri` (e.g. in `proxy_pass`) which would defeat normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out below rule:

```
rewrite ^\/\/data/app/(.*)  /data/app/$1  last;
```